# Omitting a property from hash value computation

Tags: swift

Is there a way to use `hash(into:)` to compute the hashvalue of a struct/class whilst omitting certain properties from being used?

i.e.

```
struct CacheItem: Codable, Hashable {
    let val1: Int
    let val2: Int
    let date: Date = Date()

    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(val1) // leave out date for computing hash value
        hasher.combine(val2)
    }
}
```

I was hoping this would work:

```
let cache = Set<CacheItem>()
let item1 = CacheItem(val1: 0, val2: 0)
let item2 = CacheItem(val1: 0, val2: 0)

cache.insert(item1)
assert(cache.contains(item2))
```

However, it didn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `Set` is a collection of unique objects, and equality is based on comparison with `==`. Equal objects must have the same hash value, but not the other way around: Distinct objects can have the same hash value. (A simple example: There are 2<sup>64</sup> possible hash values, but infinitely many strings. So there are necessarily distinct strings with the same hash value.)

Hashable collections (like `Set` and `Dictionary`) use the hash value in their implementation (e.g. to put different objects into different “buckets”) but they never use the hash value *alone* to determine equality.

The default implementation of `==` compares all (stored) properties for equality. Therefore, in your case, if `item1` and `item2` have the same `val1` and `val2` but different `date` then they are different objects, even if they have the same hash value.

If you want that objects with same `val1` and `val2` but different `date` are considered equal then you must implement `==` yourself:

```
struct CacheItem: Codable, Hashable {
    // ...
    
    static func ==(lhs: CacheItem, rhs: CacheItem) -> Bool {
        return lhs.val1 == rhs.val1 && lhs.val2 == rhs.val2
    }
}
```

Then

```
var cache = Set<CacheItem>()
let item1 = CacheItem(val1: 0, val2: 0)
let item2 = CacheItem(val1: 0, val2: 0)

cache.insert(item1)
print(cache.contains(item2))
```

will always print `true`.